# How to bulk change media item's link?

Tags: images, permalinks

Ok, so I have this website, https://community.entermedschool.com/imat-general-knowledge. If you scroll down, you'll notice that there are areas where the images don't show up. They point to some other website which I took down. For example, in that link above, the first image that doesn't show up is this:

[image]

https://studylions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Graph-1.svg

What I want to do is change the "studylions" part to "community.entermedschool". But I want to do it in bulk for all the images in the website which start with "studylions". How can I do this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You'll need a database search replace, the same kind that most site migration tutorials cover

Comment: Oh ok. So my website is hosted on a digital ocean droplet. How can I access the database and how can I do the search and replace? Do you have any tutorials to help with this?

Comment: No, accessing your database isn't something I can help with, you will need assistance from the person who set up your database. Connecting to a database isn't a WordPress specific thing though, a quick google search should give you millions of results, with hundreds of options for software, and you will need details that are specific to you and only you such as the DB username/password/host. Literally any tutorial you find that covers migrating a WP site that changes the URL will hold the solution ( and there are multiple ways to do it too )

Comment: I got access to the database now, how can I actually fix it?